# Memory related variables in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Hi I am New to spark and I have a doubt in one thing i:e

I read a 4.2 gb CSV file to a spark dataframe and Persist it by

```
df_spark = spark.read_csv('data.csv',header=True)
df_spark.persist()  ###so MEMORY_ONLY
df_spark.count()   ### 6722244 which is correct
# my spark conf is 
spark.driver.memory      48g
spark.memory.fraction    0.7
spark.driver.maxResultSize 4g
spark.memory.storageFraction   0.3
```

But after persist in spark UI localhost:4040, in storage tab I can see Size_in_ Memory is 1204.7 Mb. If I persists it (MEMORY_ONLY), should not it be 4.2 gb? Also the above setting in env.sh, shows how all the memory calculation happens.If possible can anybody explain how much I have to run a job((48*(1-0.7) I guess from the above set up).

Please help me clear my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

1) MEMORY_ONLY mode stores deserialized Java objects in the JVM. Now, the size of deserialized object is completely different from the size it occupies in a csv file. For example, a floating point number "1.2" in csv file takes 3 bytes whereas a "double" in memory takes 8 bytes, and a Double object takes even more number of bytes (due to space overhead from Java objects). So, that explains why we can not expect CSV size on disk to match with the number that you see on the storage tab of Spark UI.

2) I am just curious about how and where you are running this job? Your mention of "localhost:4040" says that you are running locally but then your driver memory is 48GB. That is a LOT. You should not use local mode to process large datasets, and in a typical seup, driver JVM is small and executor memory tend to be large (depending on the problem size and characteristics). Another thing that puzzles me the size of dataset in memory 1204GB i.e., 1.2 TB ... which is again very large when compared to raw data set of 4.2GB. What data do you have in that CSV file?

Comment: @Shirish-There was a typo,,,it is 1204 Mb. I edited that.. And I am runnning my job on a single machine..of 64Gb RAM.4cpu. If I consider your point#1 then  RAM  used should be more than 4.2 Gb while persist. So Size_in_Memory??

Comment: We can not perfectly say `size_in_memory` is greater or lesser than CSV size on hard drive. Contrary to the example I gave before, consider a double value 1.2345678923456789 takes 18 bytes in CSV and only 8 bytes in JVM (with `double` type). So, you can have smaller or larger JVM footprint when compared to CSV. You can "generally" expect JVM size  to be larger if there are a lot of numerics/integers in your data, but need not always be the case.

Comment: ... it totally depends on the data.

Comment: @Shirish-Plz confirm "As per my data, the 4.2 gb csv file when persisted as MEMORY_ONLY took 1204.7 Mb of RAM Space(from that 48Gb *(1-0.7)) ". Ignore what kind of data i have in that csv and how JVM Stores it...:)

Comment: As you can find in the documentation, `MEMORY_ONLY` stores your data in `deserialized` format i.e., in the form of actual Java objects. The type of those objects govern the JVM footprint.